# Recyclerview is not updated with new Data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fragment, firebaseui

Hiy guys,

I have a fragment with a `RecyclerView`in it. That `RecyclerView` is populated by a Firebase 'DatabaseReference' object and on that reference I have added a ValueListener as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
        savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


   databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                   //Do something
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                   // Getting Post failed, log a message
                   Log.w(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
               }
           });

         ItemRecyclerViewAdapter  adapter = new ItemRecyclerViewAdapter(activity, itemsDatabaseReference);
           adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
           // use a linear layout manager
          RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
           recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
           RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
           recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
           DividerItemDecoration itemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),
                   DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST);
           recyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);
           recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

`ItemRecyclerViewAdapter` extends `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. The problem is that `onDataChange` happens after `onResume` so that at times the recycler is empty. What I can't understand is the fact that the recycler view is not always empty. Sometimes data are shown and sometimes not.

Thanks

Comment: have you called to adapter.notifyDatasetChaged() on your code upon adding any data to recycler view

Comment: Hi @ujjwalmainali, with or without calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` does not matter. The point is the recycler view is not always empty. So I myself do not really understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you are using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` (or any class extended from that) as your `RecyclerView` adapter, you should set `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false)`. So the `recyclerView` knew that data is constantly updated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually onResume(); is strictly bound with activity onResume();

If you are using viewpager then there is a method in fragment

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    //do your logic . updating recycler view
}
```

if you are infalting in framelayout

then you can update in onViewCreated();

Comment: Hi @Godwin. I am not using viewpager

Comment: so you are using Framelayout to inflate the fragment

Comment: Hi @Godwin, exactly.

Comment: Then move the update code from onresume to onviewCreated and test :)