# RecyclerView with firebase remains blank sometimes, but shows items sometimes

Tags: android, android-fragments, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

This question has an answer here [Recyclerview is not updated with new Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299450/recyclerview-is-not-updated-with-new-data) but it is not working for me. I dont understand why sometimes the recyclerView shows items but sometimes it won't show. I'm using four framents with viewPager. It is not an internet issue since other fragments display data from the internet. I have tried using firebaseRecycler adapter , custom adapter and even listView in place of recyclerView. 
Here is the code for my fragement. Please help me.

```
public class FragmentTips extends Fragment {
    public RecyclerView recyclerListView;
    public MyRecyclerAdapter myAdapter;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    TextView loading;
    View v;
    SwipeRefreshLayout refresher;
    List<Model> listPosts = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, container, false);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        creatingLayouts();

        final NativeExpressAdView adView = (NativeExpressAdView) v.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public void creatingLayouts() {

        refresher = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.refresher);
        //refresher.setRefreshing(true);
        refresher.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.blue, R.color.lightBlue, R.color.deepPurple, R.color.purple, R.color.pink, R.color.orange, R.color.red);
        refresher.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (myAdapter != null) {
                    updateAdapter();

                }
            }
        });
        loading = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.loading);

        recyclerListView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerListView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        myAdapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(getContext());
        updateAdapter();
        recyclerListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    }


    //update adapter
    public void updateAdapter() {


        listPosts.clear();
        databaseReference.child("winbet").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                listPosts.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Model.class));
                displayPosts(listPosts);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }


    public void displayPosts(List<Model> ls) {
        refresher.setRefreshing(false);
        loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        recyclerListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        myAdapter.setData(ls);
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

Comment: Use this library is better to working with both firebase and RecyclerView... https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: Anas Mehar, thanks for you response but I have tried using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter a component of that FirebaseUI library but it's just the same issue.

Comment: I think first you check the firebase sample app in which include all the usage of firebasearrayadapter. Unfortunately in my case firebase sample link not respond please check out the firebase database sample..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you guys. I found the solution finally. It isn't related with the code. If anyone ever faces such an issue. The problem was that i was using the free firebase plan and the connections allowed are only 100, so it was reaching the peak since i have many users. The solution is to upgrade**